# Tilda собственное описание для каждой вариации

Tags: tilda

Каждый товар в интернет-магазине на Тильда имеет вариацию. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при смене варианта товара - менялось описание которое соответствует именно этой вариации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На 2021 год - Тильда не умеет подставлять нужный текст для разных вариаций.

Я решил этот вопрос так:

## 1. Добавляем собственный код (блок T123) в подвал сайта

Вставляем этот код:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // check if now open product page
    if($('.t-store').length){
        // set data attr for select and options
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        var select = $('.js-product-edition-option-variants')[0];
            for(let i = 0; i < select.length; i++){
                let sVal = i+1;
                select[i].setAttribute("data-s", "m"+sVal);
            }
        }, 1000);
    
        // actions on change select
        $(document).on('change','.js-product-edition-option-variants',function(){
            let currentOption = $('.js-product-edition-option-variants')[0].options[ $('.js-product-edition-option-variants')[0].selectedIndex ].getAttribute('data-s');
            $('.js-store-prod-text a').css('display','none');
            $('.js-store-prod-text a[href="#'+currentOption+'"]').css('display','block');
        });
    }
});
</script>

<style>
/* style links like a simple text */
    .js-store-prod-text a{
        color: #000 !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        cursor: default !important;
        pointer-events: none !important;
    }

    /* hide all links in text and show first (for first variation) */

    .js-store-prod-text a{
        display: none;
    }

    .js-store-prod-text a:nth-child(1){
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

## 2. Настраиваем товары

• Заходим в настройки товара, находим поле "Текст".

• В него мы пропишем нужные тексты для всех вариантов товара по очереди.

• По очереди выделяем текст, делаем из него ссылку и каждой
[image: Делаем ссылку]

• В поле URL прописываем #m1 - для первой вариации, #m2 - для второй и т.д.
[image: Атрибуты ссылки]

## Пример из файла для импорта

В файле импорта используйте обычные HTML теги.

```
<a href="#m1">
    Это описание для <b> первой вариации </b> товара
</a>
<a href="#m2">
    Это описание для второй вариации товара
</a>
<a href="#m3">
    Это описание для третий вариации товара
</a>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]